# Easier way to clear all images in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

so i have a software when ever i click a button a image is displayed but when i click the next button another image is displayed making the previous image false

```
'When Button1 is clicked do'
PicBasketball.Visible = True

'Flase'
PicBoxing.Visible = False
PicSoccer.Visible = False
PicCanoeing.Visible = False
PicGolf.Visible = False
PicSwimming.Visible = False
PicRugby.Visible = False
```

Just wondering if there is a easier method to do this instead of setting each image false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to show your images at the same position of your form (i.e. your picture boxes are put in the very same spot), you could get use of a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and use only one picture box instead. Each image is then accessible via an index, which you should save in a variable to keep track of which image you are currently showing.

```
'Class level (outside any Sub or Function, but inside Public Class).
Dim Images As New List(Of Image)
Dim ImageIndex As Integer = 0
```

Adding images:

```
Images.Add(Image.FromFile("your file path here"))
'or:
Images.Add(your image object)
```

Removing images:

```
Images.RemoveAt(zero-based index)
```

Next image:

```
ImageIndex += 1
If ImageIndex >= Images.Count Then ImageIndex = 0 'Going back to the beginning if we're at the last image.

YourPictureBox.Image = Images(ImageIndex)
```

Previous image:

```
ImageIndex -= 1
If ImageIndex < 0 Then ImageIndex = Images.Count - 1 'Going to the last image if we're in the beginning.

YourPictureBox.Image = Images(ImageIndex)
```

Things to keep in mind when using a `List(Of T)`:

- Accessing an image is done by passing its index to the list:

  ```
  Images(3) 'Returns the fourth (4th) image.
  ```
- The index is zero-based, meaning the first item has index 0, the second index 1 and so on (as seen in the above example index 3 = the 4th item).

Answer (score 0):

Make a function called `SetVisible` to do this:

- Accept a string parameter called PictureName
- Loop through all the controls, filter the ones that are image type, and that start with "Pic" and set `visible = False` for all of them
- Loop through all the controls, filter the ones that are image type, and match the  "PictureName" and set `visible = True`

You can then call it like this:

```
SetVisible (PicBoxing)
SetVisible (PicSoccer)
SetVisible (PicCanoeing)
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the picture boxes to a collection will help.

```
Dim myPBs As New List(Of PictureBox)
Dim curVis As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'if ALL of the pictureboxes on the form
    ' are part of this there is
    'an easier way, but the long way works
    myPBs.Add(PictureBox1)
    myPBs.Add(PictureBox2)
    myPBs.Add(PictureBox3)

    For Each pb As PictureBox In myPBs
        pb.Visible = False 'initial setting
    Next

    curVis = myPBs(0) 'show first one
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub

Dim ShowPB As Integer = Integer.MaxValue - 1 'which index being shown
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    curVis.Visible = False
    ShowPB += 1
    If ShowPB >= myPBs.Count Then
        ShowPB = 0 'reset
    End If
    curVis = myPBs(ShowPB)
    curVis.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It might not be the most elegant solution (none of the answers so far are), but it is a solution that is better than the original one.

Comment: My major complaint about SO, down voting without comments.